# TypeError: Guerrier.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'armure'

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Personnage:
    def __init__(self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience):
        self.nom = nom
        self.sexe = sexe
        self.couleur = couleur
        self.pdv = pdv
        self.experience = experience

    def attaquer(self):
        print(f"{self.nom} attaque l'ennemi.")

    def seDefendre(self):
        print(f"{self.nom} se defend contre l'attaque ennemie.")


class Guerrier(Personnage):
    def __init__(self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience, force, armure):
        super().__init__(nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience)
        self.force = force
        self.armure = armure

    def attaquer(self):
        print(f"{self.nom} assene un puissant coup avec sa force de {self.force}.")

    def seDefendre(self):
        print(f"{self.nom} se protege avec son armure de {self.armure}.")


class Mage(Personnage):
    def __init__(self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience, intelligence, sorts):
        super().__init__(nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience)
        self.intelligence = intelligence
        self.sorts = sorts

    def lancer_sort(self):
        print(f"{self.nom} lance un sort puissant avec son intelligence.")

class GuerrierMage(Guerrier, Mage):
    def __init__(self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience, force, armure):
        Guerrier.__init__( nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience, force, armure)
        Mage.__init__( nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience,intelligence,sorts)


# Creation d'une instance de la classe GuerrierMage
guerriermage1 = GuerrierMage("GuerrierMage1", "masculin", "rouge", 100, 10, 8, "arrmure")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bureau\code.py", line 45, in <module>
    guerriermage1 = GuerrierMage("GuerrierMage1", "masculin", "rouge", 100, 10, 8, "arrmure")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Bureau\code.py", line 40, in __init__
    Guerrier.__init__( nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience, force, armure)
TypeError: Guerrier.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'armure'
```

I have a problem with this code. It's causing an error, but I can't figure out where it might be coming from. I'm new to programming. I tried to solve the problem with ChatGPT, but even with such a basic issue, it is unable to help me.

Comment: Note that `intelligence` and `sorts` are undefined names in your code...

Comment: You have multiple problems in that code. I advise to first test smaller pieces of code before you add things.

Comment: I have been testing different pieces of code for two days, but I can't find the problem. That's why I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

The rote solution to the error would be to add `self` parameters to your __init__ calls within GuerrierMage's constructor, like so:

```
class GuerrierMage(Guerrier, Mage):
    def __init__(self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience, force, armure):
        Guerrier.__init__( self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience, force, armure)
        Mage.__init__( self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience,intelligence,sorts)
```

Unfortunately, you have other problems. Like trincot mentioned, intelligence and sorts are not parameters of your GuerrierMage constructor, and values are not provided in your instantiation.

Furthermore, `super()` in the constructors of both Guerrier and Mage should be replaced with Personnage. Don't forget to add `self` as a parameter. This is because `super()` returns the Mage class rather than the inherited Personnage class when called from the Guerrier constructor called from the GuerrierMage constructor. I'm not sure why this occurs, though, so hopefully someone can answer.

Here's some test code that exemplifies this strange behavior:

```
class Personnage:
    def __init__(self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience):
        self.nom = nom
        self.sexe = sexe
        self.couleur = couleur
        self.pdv = pdv
        self.experience = experience

    def attaquer(self):
        print(f"{self.nom} attaque l'ennemi.")

    def seDefendre(self):
        print(f"{self.nom} se defend contre l'attaque ennemie.")

    def whois(self):
        print("An instance of personnage is being created")


class Guerrier(Personnage):
    def __init__(self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience, force, armure):
        Personnage.__init__(self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience)
        self.force = force
        self.armure = armure
        super().whois()

    def attaquer(self):
        print(f"{self.nom} assene un puissant coup avec sa force de {self.force}.")

    def seDefendre(self):
        print(f"{self.nom} se protege avec son armure de {self.armure}.")


class Mage(Personnage):
    def __init__(self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience, intelligence, sorts):
        Personnage.__init__(self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience)
        self.intelligence = intelligence
        self.sorts = sorts
        super().whois()

    def lancer_sort(self):
        print(f"{self.nom} lance un sort puissant avec son intelligence.")

    def whois(self):
        print("An instance of mage is being created")

class GuerrierMage(Guerrier, Mage):
    def __init__(self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience, force, armure, intelligence, sorts):
        print("initializing guerrier from within guerriermage")
        Guerrier.__init__(self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience, force, armure)
        print("initializing mage from within guerriermage")
        Mage.__init__(self, nom, sexe, couleur, pdv, experience, intelligence, sorts)


print("Sample guerrier...")
guerrier = Guerrier("GuerrierMage1", "masculin", "rouge", 100, 10, 8, "arrmure")

print()

print("Sample guerrier mage...")
guerriermage1 = GuerrierMage("GuerrierMage1", "masculin", "rouge", 100, 10, 8, "arrmure", 10, 10)
```

Outputting:

```
Sample guerrier...
An instance of personnage is being created

Sample guerrier mage...
initializing guerrier from within guerriermage
An instance of mage is being created
initializing mage from within guerriermage
An instance of personnage is being created
```